# How to use rpush in two rails applications sharing same database?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently developing an **API** for an **existing application** in Rails 4 **both the existing application and the API share the same database but work separately as two independent apps**. The purpose of the API is to be available to respond requests from an Android app.

One of the functionalities I have is to create a post from the Android App and every time a post is created I should send a user notification to all the android users. I am doing this thanks to the **gem rpush 2.2.0**

My queues are working just fine but I keep getting this error every time someone creates a post from the Android app

```
**Uninitialized constant Rpush::Gcm**
```

**Rpush was already implemented in the existing application** but not in the API. What I tried to do was to do `rpush init` IN THE API PROJECT and it is done just fine but when I do the migrations they don't get finished because there are some tables already created by the `rpush init` that was done in the existing application, I deleted the migrations made in the API and test i

**How can I make rpush work in two different applications that share the same database?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one app needs the migrations. The other you can init with `rpush init --no-active-record`. You still need rpush in the Gemfile.